# what is the use of NSLocalizedString and when to use?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

**What is the use of `NSLocalizedString`?**

```
self.textfiled.text=NSLocalizedString(@"testing", @"test")];
```

When i execute the same i got the `textfield` displayed only testing? What will be the use of second Parameter then??

Comment: Have you tried reading Apple's docs about i18n?

Comment: I think you need read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second parameter will be used as a prompt to translators about context of string being used in your application. It will be added to file generated by [genstring](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/genstrings.1.html) tool, output will be something like:

```
self.textfiled.text = NSLocalizedString(@"AboutUserKey", @"Title for about user button")];
...
// en/Localizable.string
/* Title for about user button */
"AboutUserKey" = "About";

// ru/Localizable.string
/* Title for about user button */
"AboutUserKey" = "О пользователе";
```

Comment: Can you provide real time example ??

Answer (score 1):

I won't get into details but long story short, it is used for creating an application which will be shown in various languages. It is a macro that returns a string, according to the locale of the device. Let's assume you are writing an app which will have an english and turkish version. You need to have at least two different versions of localizable.strings file, one of English and one for Turkish. The format is the same for both:

```
/* Cancel button text */ 
"Cancel" = "Cancel";
```

and for TR:

```
/* Cancel button text */
"Cancel" = "İptal";
```

Note that the format is not "english" = "turkish", it is "key" = "value" in both versions. It will be created by genstrings if you provide an NSLocalizedString macro in your code such as:

NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel button text")]

NSLocalizedString finds the localizable.strings version from the app bundle and loads the string according to the device's locale. Note that it wont help you change language during runtime; but it will change the app language if you go to settings, change locale and restart your app.